# Is there any faster alternative to stripe.Customer.retrieve function?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

This code in python is slow:

```
import stripe

stripe.Customer.retrieve(customerid)
```

How can I make it run faster? Any alternative to `retrieve` function?

Comment: No, there's no alternative. You can't avoid calling the Stripe API to get information from them.

Comment: That code makes an API call over the network so it's always going to have a little latency. If you need some information much quicker in some kind of time-sensitive environment, you might want to set up your system such that it replicates some of the Stripe Customer details in a local database and query that instead.